# Using double negatives to test for conditions

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions

To validate user inputs, I am unsure of which of two alternatives is better

## 1

```
isNull( Object input )
```

## 2

```
notNull( Object input )
```

apache's commons lang library chose #2 but I am uncomfortable with double negatives. What do you say ?

Comment: If I want to test if something is not null, I can use (a) !isNull(o) and (b) notNull( o ). The double negative happens when you invoke !notNull(o)

Answer (score 4):

To me, double negatives is always a bad thing.
I'd say stick to isNull. Checking for nullity then makes sense while reading.
The opposite would be

```
if (! isNull(o) )
    // ...
```

which reads out "if not is null". Sure it sounds retarded read out loud, but it makes more sense than checking for nullity with option #1.

```
if (! isNotNull(o))
    // ...
```

A statement which makes you rewind and say "hey, wait a minute... if not is not...".

---

**But** if there is a standard already with having negatives in method names, stick to it. Standards are good things, and should not be broken just because someone is "uncomfortable".

Comment: I agree. Think about the maintenance of the code. If you had an object with a boolean attribute A, you usually would implement the (getter) as isA().From a logical point of view, it would be the same if Null should be tested this way. For an attribute B, you could have a method like isBNull(), which will return true if B has null value.So if you want to test an object for null, the logical approach is to ask isNull(o) and take action depending on the returned value. You could negate the statement if you have to, like (! isNull(o)). it Will be much easier to maintain the code few months later.

Answer (score 1):

I am uncomfortable with functions which are longer than the code they replace.

I would use x == null or x != null.  I agree that double negative isn't clear either.

A puzzle for you, when is (s != s) true? A good example of confusing behaviour. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think it makes much difference.

If you are designing your own API, implement it the way you are most comfortable with.  Indeed, there's no strong reason to not to implement both `isNull` and `notNull` if that makes you feel happier.

But I think it would be silly to abandon plans to use some third-party library *solely* because you are "uncomfortable with" double negatives.  They really aren't that confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here depends on so many considerations, of which some are:

- What does your programming environment support most naturally?
- What does other similar code in the same project do?
- What coding standards are you working to, if any?
- Which approach is easier to understand for others reading your code?

If you want a more considered answer, do let us know some more of the details. In the meantime, my top tip would be to go for whatever enhances readability of the code: you want to give future maintainers as much help as you can.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by the question. If the methods in question are just returning a boolean depending upon whether the argument is `null`, then `== null` or `!= null` are much better.

However, the reference to Apache Commons Lang seem to indicate that this is validity checking, and an appropriate exception should be thrown is the reference is `null`. In that case you can't invert the output easily.

FWIW, it looks as if JDK7 will introduce a `notNull` method, as discussed on an appropriate mailing list, something along the lines of:

```
public static <T> T notNull(T obj)
```

Used as:

```
import static java.util.Object.notNull;

public final MyClass {
    private final Thing thing;
    public MyClass(Thing thing) {
        this.thing = notNull(thing);
    }
    ...
```